# What is the alternative to Gson in android studios

Tags: java, android, gson, jcenter

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIJaC.png) I am developing an android application for my college project and I ran into an error; " Cannot resolve symbol Gson".

I tried adding the `jcenter()` repository in my build config to resolve the problem....but still it's not working. Later I came to know that `jcenter()` had been deprecated...Now how do I resolve my problem?? Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: try using maven central instead. if you use gradle then you can try `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10'` in `dependencies` and `mavenCentral()` in `repositories` . No need to replace gson with anything else, it's an issue with dependency resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't include the `jcenter()` repository in your build config to avoid getting outdated dependencies. according to the official documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/jcenter-migration

You can use `mavenCentral()`, in your project level `build.gradle` add `repositories { google()  // Google's Maven repository mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository }` and in app level `build.gradle` add  `implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.10'`

Comment: Appreciate me by upvoting this answer if this helps you